# Does UK red-list rules apply to airside layovers (to US)?

Tags: usa, uk, layovers, british-airways, h1b-visas

I am planning a same-day layover at LHR (airside) from a red-list country to USA as destination (on h1b visa). Would that be allowed with current/upcoming rules? I have checked all rules at gov.uk but couldn't find anything explicit that layovers wouldn't be possible arriving from a red-list country.

Comment: Note that visitors on a H1B visa are banned from entering the US if they have been in any of the banned countries (including the UK) in the last 14 days, even if it was only for airside transit, unless they qualify for and obtained a NIE.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will definitely check for NIE and if I can apply for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will NOT be allowed travel on this itinerary.  You will be denied boarding at your point of origin.

[Current regulations](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/covid-19-travel-restrictions-and-exceptions.html) disallow most travelers from entering the US if they have been "physically present" in any of a number of countries within 14 days prior of their entry to the US - and this list includes the UK.

For the purposes of these regulations, being in transit is considered being "physically present" in the country.

As you are attempting the enter using a H-1B visa, you are almost certainly not covered by any of the exceptions for this rule.  The airline will realize this at your original point of departure, and not allow you to board the flight to the UK.

Comment: Destination rules apply for sure, but what if I had NIE approved by US? Would I still be denied boarding at the origin?

Comment: @halloween42 You may still be denied boarding. The airlines will err on the side of caution in almost all cases and rather deny a traveller than give the benefit of the doubt. That sucks, but it is something you will have to keep in mind. You best bet is check with the airline before traveling and, if possible, get a written statement that you are free to travel. That might help at the gate if a gate-attendant tries to refuse you anyway.

Comment: Presuming you are able to obtain an NIE (the vast majority of H-1B holders would not be eligible) then yes, you would be allowed board/enter.  However unless you're coming from a country on the list it would make far more sense to simply re-route to avoid any of the listed countries if that's at all possible.

Comment: @Tonny The NIE is a stamp in your passport, put there by the US consulate. About as official as it gets!

Comment: @Doc I know, but with current Covid concerns it is totally possible that an ill-informed gate-handler at the airport will refuse boarding anyway. NIE not withstanding. In that case anything official looking from the airline itself might help.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/incident/coronavirus/entry-requirements the following applies to airside transits for destinations outside the Common Travel Area:

For destinations in the rest of the world (outside the Common Travel Area), you won’t need to stop your journey. You’re still able to connect flights at London Heathrow, Gatwick or any other UK airport, but you must stay airside (do not pass border control) and go straight through Flight Connections. If you do not pass border control, you will not need to quarantine. You still need to comply with the entry requirements for your final destination.

So yes, your itinerary is currently allowed, as far as UK Covid travel rules are concerned. The USA is a different matter.

Comment: Whilst much of this answer may be correct from the UK perspective, it does not cover the USA portion of the trip which is not allowed. Without correct onward documentation for the US, the passenger will not be allowed board the flight to the UK, so most of this answer is moot! (except for the last sentence, which is just outright wrong!)

Comment: @Doc The question specifically asks about the UK’s transit rules. I will amend the answer to be explicit.